# Tell if the matrix can be diagonalized without calculations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can the following matrix be diagonilized? First say yes or no, then explain why.

\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 1 && 1 && 1 && 1 \\
0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: No. Its eigenvalues are $1,0,0,0,0$, with corresponding eigenvectors $(1,0,0,0,0),(-1,1,0,0,0),(-1,0,0,1,0),(-1,0,0,0,1)$, so the dimension of the eigenspace is $4$. For it to be diagonalisable, the dimension must be $5$

Comment: ...your orders have been fulfilled, master...

Comment: Is possible to see eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors without any calculations?

Comment: It was quite easy to see them in this example. However, I prefer Arpan's answer below, it is a much nicer method.

Answer (score 5):

The matrix has $rank=2$, now if it's diagnosable then exactly two entries of the diagonal must be nonzero and other $3$ zero, also the entries of the diagonal are the eigenvalues, now the only eigenvalues are $1$ and $0$, and algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ cannot be more than $1$, hence exactly two entries of the diagonal matrix cannot be non-zero, hence a contradiction!